# How to simulate multiple users

Tags: angularjs, node.js, testing, performance-testing, traffic-simulation

I built an App with Angular on the front end and NodeJS on the back.

The app is behaving funny when a few people are using it simultaneously.

I want to make some changes and then test it with a bunch of people, but I can't keep bugging my friends to do so.

Is there a good automated way to test how it behaves with a whole bunch of users?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to setup concurrent users performing the same actions or different ones...

Answer (score 2):

If you needed to test complex scenarios and 250 virtual users would be sufficient, try a [free version of StresStimulus](http://www.stresstimulus.com/features/editions).

Comment: Yes, it will work with NodeJS. It works with any server framework due to its proprietary autocorrelation. When it replays a recorded scenario, the server cannot distinguish that requests come not from a physical client, but from virtual users. Additionally it has a powerful test designer that makes it easy to parameterize complex application scenarios without manual scripting.  If you are interested to consider a commercial version, a free trial includes a support session where our engineers help to make your test work. it is available here https://www.stresstimulus.com/trials/request-trial

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check out the [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).